# WebStorm keeps auto-importing the source path of ng library

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm

- Angular/cli, v17
- WebStorm 2023.3

I have extracted some parts of my custom test utilities into a library (`ng g lib my-testing-utils`) and everything seems to work great, except WebStorm doesn't seem to pick up the `my-testing-utils` build as the import path, so when an auto-import is inserted it uses some relative path, `from '../projects/my-testing-utils/src/lib'` rather than `from 'my-testing-utils'`. When I manually correct the path, the app still builds, it's just an annoyance.

What would be the way to make WebStorm notice the new path which was generated by ng cli:

```json
"paths": {
  "my-testing-utils": [
    "./dist/my-testing-utils"
  ]
},
```

I did run `ng build my-testing-utils` beforehand so the file `dist/my-testing-utils/index.d.ts` is present.